# apply rewrite rule based on 404 response code

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

i'm trying to achaive this ,

```
if request  hit www.imagesserver.com/public/images/view/3421.png
```

then

```
if response == 404
```

do

redirect  or rewrite to

```
www.imagesserver.com/public/images/view/defualt.png
```

this only apply for this path public/images/view/*.png , what is the best way to achieve this logic

Comment: its not a valid directory mapped via application

Comment: yes its a real dir

Answer (score 1):

You can use this rule in `public/images/view/.htaccess` (create it if doesn't exist):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(?!.+/defualt\.png$).+\.png$ /public/images/view/defualt.png [L,NC,R=307]
```

Comment: the path public/images/view/ is  is not exist in the file system its managed via application

Comment: No issues, you can keep this rule in `public/.htaccess` (if it exists) or in site root .htaccess

Comment: its through 404 no rewrite rule fired

Comment: lets say i requested www.imagesserver.com/public/images/view/555.png and its not exist ( the image is not exist) it should redirect me to  www.imagesserver.com/public/images/view/defualt.png

Comment: endup in infinit loop with ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Comment: thats works  but its also replace all pngs even existing one with default.png

Comment: btw i added this to thi httpd.conf file not htaccess file

Comment: That rule won't replace existing files because we have `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` condition that skips all existing files. You can use this rule in `httpd.conf` also but make sure to bounce Apache after every change.

Comment: its happening in my case , its replace all png even if its exist , not even in the same but whole website pngs replaced  .. what we are missing here

Comment: Rule is not missing anything. This condition `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` is tried and tested way to skip existing files. Enable rewrite logs (search google on how to do it) and then paste rewrite log trace in question for this request.

Comment: Also make sure this rule is very first rule in your .htaccess just below `RewriteEngine On` line.

Comment: i enabled the logs and actually its replacing all my rewrite rules  for example   applying pattern '^/web/ajax/' to uri '/web/team/default.png' rewrite '/web/images/competition/253.png' -> '/web/team/default.png'

Comment: ok, paste all rewrite log lines for this request in your question. Also paste your complete .htaccess

Comment: can we apply the only when url request pattern include  the following path  /web/images/team/  ,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154302/discussion-between-anubhava-and-jecki).

Answer (score 0):

You can't really do this once the 404 has been issued but you can do it beforehand:

```
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpg|png)$
RewriteRule ^public/images/view/.* /public/images/view/defualt.png [L,R=301]
```

This checks if the requested resource is a file or directory and only applies the rule if not.

It also makes sure the requested resource has specific image extensions - jpg/png in this case but you can extend that using the evident pattern as needed.

Next, the rewrite rule only fires if these conditions are met within `/public/images/view/`.

Next, I set this to issue a 301 redirect from the missing resource to the default image so as to clearly show the client that the image is missing.

Note: not sure if deliberate but you got a typo in your filename for default image: `defualt.png`